# adjusting mkmapview region

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm doing something that seems so simple that I can't believe it's not working, and I can't figure out what I"m doing wrong.

Basically, I'm loading an MKMapView, and it's working great; all the features I want work, except for one.  I want to have it default to a larger region than it does.  To that end, I've done the following:

```
MKCoordinateRegion biggerMap = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.MyMap.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(80.0, 80.0));
[self.MyMap setRegion:biggerMap animated:YES];
```

I don't really want 80 degrees in each direction, but I wanted to go big just to make sure that the change from the built-in default was drastic enough to notice.  Unfortunately, nothing changes.  I put this code right alongside all the code that sets the MKMapView's other parameters, and they're doing the right thing, so I know the block is executing...

Just in case it was an issue with my region not aligning nicely, I tried a second version of that second line:

```
[self.MyMap setRegion:[self.MyMap regionThatFits:biggerMap] animated:YES];
```

But that didn't fix it.

The documentation makes it seem like there just isn't that much to changing the region, so I'm stumped.  Anyone have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to change region:

```
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

myRegion.center.latitude = -31.952745;
myRegion.center.longitude = 115.857697;

// this sets the zoom level, a smaller value like 0.02
// zooms in, a larger value like 80.0 zooms out
myRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
myRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

[myMap setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: Well, it didn't at first, but just for the fun of it, I turned off the location functionality in the simulator, and without the simulated GPS, your code worked fine.  Mine didn't because it depends upon the centerpoint of the currently-viewed map (the user's current location)... I wonder if there's something else I should be doing to change the span, i.e. if changing the region isn't allowed if the map is set up to track the user's location.

Comment: Grr. No, that didn't work. Well, that's not entirely accurate: I could zoom IN more, but zooming out with progressively larger numbers did not work.

Comment: Ben, could you also try [myMap setNeedsRedisplay]; with your code?